# Improving the English of these 2 sentences

Tags: word-choice

I've written the below 2 sentences. Just so you know 'Chien' is the name of the chalet. Also not sure if it's clear but I'm trying to say all of my company's chalets have their own playroom and also all of the chalets have their own hot tub as well, however not all of them have these great views. Hope that's how you interpret it too.

"Enjoy Christmas in this truly special chalet right beside the piste. Like all of our chalets, Chien has its own playroom and hot tub, and the chalet also offers great views of the surrounding mountains from its top floor living area."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to do anything except replace "the chalet" with "it". The repetition is awkward, but the "and also" communicates well enough that this is an additional feature of Chien specifically, over and above those in the preceding clause.

Answer (score 0):

To clearly separate the quality of the views from the features that are shared with all the chalets, I would consider changing the order:

> Chien offers great views of the surrounding mountains from its
>   top-floor living area, and like all of our chalets has its own
>   playroom and hot tub.

I am also not convinced by 'great views' in a marketing context. You may wish to go with something more evocative like breathtaking/stunning/beautiful.